# Why doesn’t Carla Jean run away from Anton Chigurh?

Tags: no-country-for-old-men

In the movie No Country For Old Men why doesn’t Carla Jean Moss just run away after finding Anton Chigurh sitting in the chair?

He isn’t pointing a gun or dangerous weapon at her.

It seems she should rather have run away and then give the police a description of him and maybe they would have caught him and she could have received some justice and revenge for him killing Llewelyn.

She doesn’t seem stupid (maybe she is, because simply trying to talk it out with someone whose clearly a psychopathic killer isn’t a smart or wise choice).

Answer (score 4):

### She is petrified.

Shortly after she sees Chigurh in [this scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oGfvV3Syud8), she says "I need to sit down," and she takes a seat. Her need to sit was most likely caused by a biological reaction to fear:

> One of the ways in which the body prepares for this action is to redirect blood flow to the areas most needed, including the legs, which are needed to run away from danger. Increased blood flow to the legs can make them feel weak, tingly or like jelly. [Source](https://www.intrepidmentalhealth.com/blog/10-most-common-physical-symptoms-of-anxiety)

Even though the blood flow is to facilitate running, it can make a person feel like they cannot run.

### She believes she can reason with him.

During the scene, Carla mentions that she just buried her mother, seeking some pity. She says the money is gone, hoping to make him lose interest. And she tells him that he has no reason to hurt her, which logically is true. Unfortunately, she did not count on Chigurh keeping his word to her husband that he would kill her if her husband did not give himself up.

### She doubts she'd be able to outrun him.

She is in a skirt and in heels. He is a powerfully built man in boots. Her legs feel weak from fear, and she probably assumes he has a gun, even if she cannot see it. Running probably seems like an unlikely prospect for her.

Comment: I appreciate the response.

Comment: I appreciate the response. I already thought all of what you’ve said and at the end of the day although everything you’ve said makes sense and is what she is feeling and thinking and saying, it’s still better to try to run as you never know. I think she was set on trying to ‘change him’which we know Chigurh would not let happen due to not wanting to get caught and sick sense of being a man of his word. He did surprisingly give her a 50/50 chance but she seemed stubborn IMO which is unbelievable  considering the consequences of refusing his offer.

Comment: That’s debatable whether she should have run. Had she run, she may have given herself a small chance of escaping temporarily, though he would have come after her later. By staying, she won herself a 50-50 chance of survival and him leaving her alone forever. Personally, I think he kills her because when he leaves the house he appears to check his boots for blood (and in the book he explicitly kills her), but 50-50 still aren’t bad odds against Anton Chigurh.